# how to search and remove a subtring contains dots in a string with javascript

Tags: javascript

I wanted to search a substring (this string is contain one or more dots) in a string with javascript.
I want to use regexp to use but does not work for me.

For example:
my string is "MY FLEX L.L.C" or "MY FLEX L.L.C." or "MY FLEX CO."
and the result should be like this "MY FLEX"

anyone can show me a best way. Thanks

Comment: use replace str.replace('L.L.C.', 'CO.');

Comment: @ÁlvaroTouzón That is not at all what he's asking for.

Comment: @Santi, i suposed but there is something, i cant undedstand, where is the pattern to remove, in his example there is some noise from string start and where he wants to transformate

Comment: yeah pls note that L.L.C. and CO. are dynamic and they are in an array

here is my code:
var myarr = ["A NEW JERSEY NONPROFIT CORPORATION", "A NONPROFIT CORPORATION", "ASSOCIATION", "CLUB", "CO", "CO. ", "CO.", "COMMITTEE", "COMPANY ", "COMPANY", "CORP", "CORP. ", "CORP.", "CORPORATION ", "CORPORATION", "FOUNDATION", "FUND", "INC", "INC. ", "INC.", "INCORPORATED ", "INCORPORATED", "INSTITUTE", "LEAGUE", "LIMITED ", "LIMITED", "LTD", "LTD. ", "LTD.", "SERVICES", "SOCIETY", "SYNDICATE", "UNION"];

Comment: @HungNguyen, show the expected result from the above array

Answer (score 0):

yeah pls note that L.L.C. and CO. are dynamic and they are in an array

here is my code:

```
var needToRemoveWhenTyping = ["A NEW JERSEY NONPROFIT CORPORATION", "A NONPROFIT CORPORATION", "ASSOCIATION", "CLUB", "CO", "CO.    ", "CO.", "COMMITTEE", "COMPANY ", "COMPANY", "CORP", "CORP.    ", "CORP.", "CORPORATION    ", "CORPORATION", "FOUNDATION", "FUND", "INC", "INC.    ", "INC.", "INCORPORATED    ", "INCORPORATED", "INSTITUTE", "LEAGUE", "LIMITED  ", "LIMITED", "LTD", "LTD.  ", "LTD.", "SERVICES", "SOCIETY", "SYNDICATE", "UNION"];

for (i = 0; i < needToRemoveWhenTyping.length; i++) {
            reg = new RegExp('\\b' + needToRemoveWhenTyping[i] + '\\b', 'gi');

            if ($this.val().match(reg)) {
               // If matched then replace
                newCompName = $this.val().replace(reg, '');
                $this.val(newCompName);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Non-regex solution: https://jsfiddle.net/4jwy58z1/1/

```
function removeWordsWithDots(str) {
    var substrings = str.split(" "); //Break string into words

    for (var i = 0; i < substrings.length; i++) {
       if (substrings[i].indexOf(".") > -1) {
           substrings.splice(i,1); //Remove word if it has a .
       }
    }

    return substrings.join(" ");
 }
```

Usage:

```
var companyName = "My Business L.L.C.";
companyName = removeWordsWithDots(companyName);

console.log(companyName);
//"My Business"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create function that finds substrings with dots and then removes it from the given string. Here is regex solution:

```
function removeSubstringsWithDots(fullString) {
  var result = fullString;
  var substringsWithDots = fullString.split(' ').filter(function(str) { 
    return str.includes('.') === true; 
  }); 
  substringsWithDots.forEach(function(str) {
      var regexp = new RegExp(str);
      result = result.replace(regexp, '');
  });
  return result;
};
```

And use it:

```
var newString = removeSubstringsWithDots('some s.t.r.i.n.g');
```

Check it out: https://jsfiddle.net/38p4aggf/

Answer (score 0):

```
var needToRemoveWhenTyping = ["A NEW JERSEY NONPROFIT CORPORATION", "A NONPROFIT CORPORATION", "ASSOCIATION", "CLUB", "CO", "CO.    ", "CO.", "COMMITTEE", "COMPANY ", "COMPANY", "CORP", "CORP.    ", "CORP.", "CORPORATION    ", "CORPORATION", "FOUNDATION", "FUND", "INC", "INC.    ", "INC.", "INCORPORATED    ", "INCORPORATED", "INSTITUTE", "LEAGUE", "LIMITED  ", "LIMITED", "LTD", "LTD.  ", "LTD.", "SERVICES", "SOCIETY", "SYNDICATE", "UNION"];
// first we create a string with "|" pipe means "OR" in RegExp
var rev = needToRemoveWhenTyping.reverse();
var stringtext = rev.join("|");
// then deal with dot "." we need to escape it otherwise our match will be inaccurate 
var formattedReg = stringtext.replace(/\./ig, "\\.");
// next we got clean regEx object as following
var reg = new RegExp(formattedReg,"ig");

// rest is your code no need to use for loop since we used "|"
if ($this.val().match(reg)) {
    // If matched then replace
    newCompName = $this.val().replace(reg, '');
    // trim it in case whitespace
    newCompName.trim();
    $this.val(newCompName);
}
```